# NC-6220 Hewlett Packard keyboard - the keys for the " and @ symbols are in each others' places - what do I do?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using an NC-6220 Hewlett Packard keyboard with Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and to type the " and @ symbols I need to use the keys (plus shift) as though they were swapped round (eg. SHIFT+2 for @ and SHIFT+' for ")
 - what do I do to swap them back to the positions printed on the plastic?

It is OK for me to use because I am used to it, but if someone else is using my console, it is a headache for them and it is an accessibility issue to the 'net for folk who are not as computer-literate as me (not very computer-literate myself, actually !)

The "F" key isn't working either, but that's because it was glued back on with too much super-glue !!

I know I did something wrong when I set up the computer upon first installing Linux Ubuntu, and when I used the Guest Account the keys produce the right symbols.

I will give a million blessing points to anyone who can tell me, how I can assign specific characters to the keys on my keyboard.

:)

Answer (score 0):

How to define keyboard layout https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions

Comment: Thanks DnrDevil. That has been a good launchpad for me to find a solution. In the end I discovered how to use the System Settings - Text Entry to add alternative keyboard layouts and now I am using a normal English (UK) layout which, for some reason, I failed to select when I installed Ubuntu. Everything seems to be working fine now.